# Handling an undefined template variable in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

This is a tornado template (say, in the file logout.html) I render on an error in the logout process:

```
  {% if logout_error %}
    Oops! The logout failed. Please close all open documents and try again
  {% end %}
```

This can be called using

```
self.render("logout.html", logout_error=True)
```

If the logout is successful, I have to do

```
self.render("logout.html", logout_error=False)
```

If I ignore `logout_error=False`, I get

```
NameError: global name 'logout_error' is not defined
```

If there are a lot of flags (which are false), the keyword arguments can pile up. Is there a way I can ask the template to consider `logout_error` as `False` if it does not exist?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hacking around using `locals().get()` is one way to do it. Another, bit more orthodox is using `try`. Tornado template supports it, so you can:

```
{% try %}
  {% if logout_error %}
    Oops! The logout failed. Please close all open documents and try again
  {% end %}
{% except %}
{% end %}
```

Comment: vartec, Thanks for your answer. I'm going to mark phihag's answer as correct (in spite of yours being fine) due to its brevity

Comment: This seems like the better solution to me, especially after reading this semi-cautionary tale about locals()  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550479/python-is-using-vars-locals-a-good-practice.  (Django templates fail silently by default, don't they?)

Comment: For some reason I never got `locals().get()` to work. Your solution works fine though. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 15):

You can use

```
{% if locals().get('logout_error', False) %}
```

Substitute `False` with the value you want if the property is not set.

Comment: As @shenyan points out below, under some circumstances (for me, if you pass in the variables to the template with `render`) your variables end up in `globals`, not `locals`. I'm not sure if it's safe to rely upon this behavior - tiny bit more discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/MppS69GjZk0. The try/catch answer is ugly but is more resilient.

Answer (score 1):

{% if locals().get('logout_error', False) %} not works because variables not passed as in **kwargs;

{% if globals().has_key('logout_error') %} works to me because my variables are passed separately,
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/dyl50NO3yzE this page has more disscussion on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "Tornado way" is to not have undeclared variables. It's more zen to declare the variables explicit.

Workaround:

```
{% if 'grok' in globals() %}
  {{grok}}
{% end %}

{% if globals().get('grok_error', False) %}
  error message
{% end %}
```