# Variable in tornado template

Tags: templates, variables, tornado

I post a form with just form data(kinds of inputs), and I want to display the values when responsed from tornado server.

And when I use the variable in a template as follows:

```
<td style="width: 55%">
        <label>Fund:</label>
        <input name="fund" type="text" value="{{ fund }}">
        <span class="help-block"></span>
      </td>
```

it turns out an error, it is same as [Handling an undefined template variable in Tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139341/handling-an-undefined-template-variable-in-tornado).

So the question is how I can get a variable from request like java, eg: reqeust.getAttribute("key"); in jsp, Because I can put some variable in to request through request.setAttribute("key", value);

Anyone can help?
Thanks a lot....
And I will do appreciate if some good person provides a link to detailed tornado template doc except the official doc, which I think is too simple on template...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be achieved by add variables in method render.....

For somebody else:
If you want to submit your form with kinds of inputs as I did, and you want to redisplay your submitted data in the form, you will have to use the method render in RequestHandler, like:

```
self.render('display.html', **req_args)
```

that means you have to put the args(or request parameters) again when rendering your page.

Comment: Are you saying you found an answer to your own question? If so can you elaborate for others with the same question? Otherwise, you can add additional details by [updating your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855386/variable-in-tornado-template) instead.

Comment: No, this is an answer...not additional information. I think I can accept it, 'cause I have a test and it fits my need..

Comment: Yep, you can accept your own answer. (Thanks for posting the code. It will help the next guy)