# Using locals() and format() method for strings: are there any caveats?

Tags: python, string-formatting, local-variables, locals

Are there any disadvantages, caveats or bad practice warnings about using the following pattern?

```
def buildString(user, name = 'john', age=22):
    userId = user.getUserId()
    return "Name: {name}, age: {age}, userid:{userId}".format(**locals())
```

I had a very repetitive string generation code to write and was tempted to use this, but something about using `locals()` makes me uncomfortable. Is there any danger of unexpected behavior in this?

Edit: context

I found myself constantly writing stuff like:

```
"{name} {age} {userId} {etc}...".format(name=name, age=age, userId=userId, etc=etc)
```

Comment: I don't see anything horribly wrong with it ...

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1550479/125507

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is now an official way to do this, as of Python 3.6.0: [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).

It works like this:

```
f'normal string text {local_variable_name}'
```

E.g. instead of these:

```
"hello %(name) you are %(age) years old" % locals()
"hello {name} you are {age} years old".format(**locals())
"hello {name} you are {age} years old".format(name=name, age=age)
```

just do this:

```
f"hello {name} you are {age} years old"
```

Here's the official example:

```
>>> name = "Fred"
>>> f"He said his name is {name}."
'He said his name is Fred.'
>>> width = 10
>>> precision = 4
>>> value = decimal.Decimal("12.34567")
>>> f"result: {value:{width}.{precision}}"  # nested fields
'result:      12.35'
```

Reference:

- [Python 3.6 What's New](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)
- [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498)
- [Lexical analysis description](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Answer (score 30):

If the format string is not user-supplied, this usage is okay.

`format` is preferred over using the old `%` for string substitution.
[`locals`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) is built-in to Python and its behavior will be reliable.

I think `locals` does exactly what you need.
Just don't modify the dictionary from locals and I would say you have a pretty good solution.

If the format string is user-supplied, you are susceptible to injection attacks of all sorts of badness.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a caveat that the string never be **user-supplied**?  That could open up access to the contents of every local variable.

Comment: Straight shooting @BobStein-VisiBone, I have updated my answer.

Comment: There appears to be a very small performance overhead using locals() rather than just the variables you need, since you have an extra function call and you're constructing a larger dictionary. It's probably negligible for most applications though: I'm seeing differences of about 2% in a quick test case.

Comment: Instead of user supplied one could say it is internally generated or something, this would apply then here too

Answer (score 2):

### Pre Python 3.6 answer

This is very old, but if you find yourself using `.format` the one caveat I have encountered with passing in `**locals` is that if you don't have that variable defined anywhere, it will break. Explicitly stating what variables are passed in will avoid this in most modern IDEs.

```
foo = "bar"
"{foo} and {baz} are pair programming".format(**locals())
<exception occurs>
```

Comment: Use this: f"{foo} and {baz} are pair programming"
And you will get a NameError. But in this case the IDE can detect it.
The original solution should be avoided. Just use everywhere f-strings and enforce the use of Python 3.6+ Additionally you'll get syntax for asyncio for free.

Comment: @DeaD_EyE I think I found a case where .format is still useful: if the variables are defined after the string to format. `s = """{foo} is not {bar}"""; foo = "A"; bar = "B"; f"{s}".format(**locals())`