# Are there downsides to using Python locals() for string formatting?

Tags: python, string, formatting

This is not a duplicate, as this regards using the newer `str.format()`, *the above linked question is also of lower quality,* and I think this question is sufficiently different to justify its canonicity.

The question:

One might expect an error here, but we can provide the `str.format` method with unused keyword arguments.

```
>>> '{a}{b}'.format(a='foo', b='bar', c='baz')
'foobar'
```

This enables code like:

```
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> baz = 'fizzbuzz'
>>> '{foo}{baz}'.format(**locals())
'barfizzbuzz'
>>> baz = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> '{foo}_{baz}'.format(**locals())
'bar_2013-12-20 18:36:55.624000'
```

**Is this a good practice to do inside a closure like a function?**

```
def make_foo_time_string():
    foo = 'bar'
    baz = datetime.datetime.now()
    return '{foo}{baz}'.format(**locals())
```

What would be the possible downsides? Extra variables loaded using extra cycles? Is this a matter of convenience? **I don't recall seeing this used much, would it be considered idiomatic of Python?**

**Update** I have found a canonical suggested usage using the old style string interpolation: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips
Nevertheless, it does seem a rather old document.

> "Even better, for readability (this has nothing to do with efficiency other than yours as a programmer), use dictionary substitution:"

```
out = "<html>%(head)s%(prologue)s%(query)s%(tail)s</html>" % locals()
```

Comment: There's a new and canonical way in 3.6: formatted string literals: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498 or 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44442301/1144854

Comment: Is there a downside? I would say so, but only if the message to be formatted could ever be a variable itself. That is to say, if someone can pass you the string to format, they can basically execute arbitrary code in the form of the `__str__` (and `__repr__`?) methods of all local variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - The Zen of Python:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Here, that could (and to me, *does*) mean that it's better to spell out what you want to do. Suppose you eventually want to replace that with a method call and go from

```
>>> '{a}{b}'.format(a='foo', b='bar', c='baz')
```

to

```
>>> mymethod(a='foo', b='bar', c='baz')
```

Voila - done. But more practically, PyLint and friends can give you valuable information about the explicit version. Suppose you have:

```
foo = '123'
print '{foo}'.format(**locals())
```

Great. That works. But what if you forgot to assign to `foo`? Your code will blow up and you won't know why. Compare with:

```
print '{foo}'.format(foo=foo)
```

where PyLint will give you an "Undefined name: 'foo'" error. Yay! Bug found before you've even started to look for it.

In general, be explicit. It's Pythonic, but it's also really good practice.

Comment: You're sticking the strings `'foo'`, `'bar'`, and `'baz'` into the format string instead of the local variables `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` as in the original post. The most Pythonic way to do what you're doing is probably just `'foobar'` without using `format`…

Comment: I like debugging using `print("foo is {foo} bar is {bar} baz is {baz}".format(foo=foo,bar=bar,baz=baz))` is great to track down the errant variable ("Oh oops, no wonder my loop is terminating early, I used i**=2 instead of i*=2") and what have you. print(foo,bar,baz) is not as helpful for that.

Comment: @adsmith: Except of course when you type `print("foo is {foo} bar is {baz}"`… and don't notice the typo in your quickly-written debugging statement. Not that I've ever wasted 6 hours of a day on a stupid bug like that. :)

Comment: @abarnert I was going for the simplest possible example, just for the sake of getting the idea across. Yeah, that'd be a very heavyweight way to write that string. Don't do that. :-D

Answer (score 6):

> What would be the possible downsides? Extra variables loaded using extra cycles? Is this a matter of convenience? I don't recall seeing this used much, would it be considered idiomatic of Python?

You just hit on the biggest downside: It's not idiomatic.

And the *reason* it's not idiomatic is, as the [Zen](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says, "Explicit is better than implicit."

Obviously many people would not write `'{foo}{baz}'.format(foo=foo, baz=baz)` (especially if you get too far beyond 2 variables), because that violates DRY pretty horribly… but there's a way to do this that's just as concise as your code, and at least as explicit, and doesn't require sort-of-advanced-level knowledge like `locals`:

```
>>> '{}{}'.format(foo, baz)
```

This doesn't work when the format string is dynamic, but that's a *good* thing, because dynamic format strings are usually a red flag.

(Some people have also argued the "static-checking" benefit here—if you embed the names in the format string, you get a much less decipherable error than the simple `NameError` from using a variable that doesn't exist in the arguments to `format`. I put this in parentheses near the bottom because I personally don't think this argument is very good, even if I have seen it multiple times…)

However, as with any style/idiom question, there is no universal agreement on this one, and it gets debated regularly on python-list (and python-ideas, when someone suggests a way to make `locals()` a default for `format` or the like) until everyone stops paying attention.