# Is it possible to get formal argument names/values as a dictionary?

Tags: python, parameters

If I have a Python function defined as `f(a, b, c)`, is there a straightforward way to get a dictionary mapping the formal names to the values passed in? That is, from inside `f`, I'd like to be able to get a dictionary `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` for the call `f(1, 2, 3)`.

I'd like to do this so I can directly use the arguments and values in a string substitution, e.g. `"%(a)s %(b)s %(c)s" % d`. I could just do something like `d = dict(a=a, b=b, c=c)`, but I'd rather avoid the repetition if possible.

I know this is quite easy to do by defining `f` as `f(**kwds)`, but that also makes it less obvious what arguments the function expects. It looks like there'd probably be some way to do this via the `inspect` module, but it'd probably be too complex to be worthwhile.

I suspect there's no good answer to this question as posed, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. Alternative approaches for accomplishing what I described above would be welcome too.

Comment: Would function(*args) do the job?

Comment: There is [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#locals), although it's not strictly limited.

Comment: What you're doing may cause you problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550479/python-is-using-vars-locals-a-good-practice It's not quite as bad as using `locals`, but it couples the function signature and argument names to the format string in a way you'll regret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `locals()` for the current scope:

```
>>> def f(a, b, c):
...     param_values = locals()  # Line must be very first in function.
...     print(param_values)

>>> f(1, 2, 3)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Conveniently, this seems to be the exact output that you want. In my opinion, this is the best way to do it from *inside the function* as you specified.

Comment: That's fine, but if you define any variable within the function before the print, it will end up in the dictionary.

Comment: @msvalkon Very good point. Modified so that the `print` statement can go anywhere.

Comment: This requires you to already know which keys were the args, so it's not truly dynamic.

Comment: I initially had it in my mind that filtering out the other locals would be problematic, but on further reflection, I think I can live with saving things off at the beginning.

Comment: @jjlin: Be careful with closure variables. `locals` includes those.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, not relevant for my current situation, but definitely something that would point towards a more complex `inspect`-based solution.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(a,b,c):
...     pass
... 
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo).args
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Now you can filter `locals()` based on those.

```
>>> x = 'outer'
>>> G = 'GLOBAL'
>>> def foo(a, b, c=1, *splat, **splatsplat):
...     global G
...     d = 'inner'
...     b = 'stomped'
...     print(locals())
...     print(inspect.getargspec(foo))
...     
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 'splat1', 'splat2', named='potato')
{'splatsplat': {'named': 'potato'}, 'splat': ('splat1', 'splat2'), 'd': 'inner', 'b': 'stomped', 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs='splat', keywords='splatsplat', defaults=(1,))
```

The only thing I don't know how to get is to recover the original value of `b`; I think that's probably impossible.

Comment: Only problem here is that OP wanted to do it from within the function. This does not fulfil that criteria.

Comment: Yes it does.  You can do it from within the function!

Comment: Sorry, just read the documentation for `getargspec`. I skimmed over your answer too quickly and saw that it was not within the function and thought it was not quite right. My apologies, never would have thought of this. A very dynamic solution.

Comment: Then why didn't you show its use inside a function?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious.  I will add it now.

Comment: I was looking at `getargvalues(currentframe(0))` which gives `ArgInfo(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, locals={'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2})` for `f(1, 2, 3)` for instance... However, amending any of those variables inside the function before doing the check will give you the modified value - not the values in the original call - which is what I believe the OP is after.

Comment: I was mulling over something like this, but one aspect I didn't really like about `inspect`-based solutions is you seem to have to provide the function name, which is quasi-needless repetition, and inconvenient if I decide to change the function name. Nevertheless, +1 for a more concrete solution (not quite complete without the filtering step).

Comment: @jjlin see the comment above yours for digging the function name out dynamically

Comment: @wim Ah, didn't notice that. Might consider adding that to the answer for anyone not wading through the comments in detail. Thanks to Jon Clements also.

Comment: Just calling `getargspec()` doesn't provide a dictionary "mapping the formal names to the values passed in". A dictionary like that is needed for the string interpolation the OP wants to do. Since it's OK to have extra stuff in the dictionary, `locals()` is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with two functions, one with a nice interface and the other with the implementation:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    """Docstring"""
    return _f(a, b, c)

def _f(**kwargs):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid even more repetition by instead creating a generic function that does the string substitution as well. The following works in both Python 2.7.6 and 3.3.4:

```
import inspect
import sys

def print_func_args(call_stack_depth=1):
    frame = sys._getframe(call_stack_depth)
    funcname = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function
    func = frame.f_globals[funcname]
    f_locals = frame.f_locals
    args = inspect.getargspec(func).args
    print(', '.join(('{}={}'.format(arg, f_locals[arg]) for arg in args)))

def foo(a, b, c):
    local_var = 42
    print_func_args()

foo(1, 2, 3)  # -> a=1, b=2, c=3
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution that would be easy to use in any random function, and 3 somewhat-involved lines of code isn't my idea of that. Can that code be moved out into another function, like `get_local_args_dict()` or something? The main issue would seem to be how to have that function pass `foo` or equivalent to `getargspec()`.

Comment: Yes, it possible to move them to a separate function -- see updated answer.

Comment: I guess I wasn't that clear -- can it be done without explicitly passing the name `foo` from within `foo`?

Comment: It's possible for a global function, but I haven't figured-out a truly general way so far -- unfortunately, I don't have much more time to work on this right now.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a more general solution, and more technically interesting as well. I don't have time to look at it in detail now, but will consider updating the accepted answer later.

Comment: I think it is better to get the function name with the help of  `traceback.extract_stack`, since `sys._getframe` is "private"

Comment: @wim: I don't really want the function name, just used it as a way to get to the function itself. WWIW, `inspect.currentframe()` uses `sys._getframe()` itself. It _is_ documented and I think has a leading underscore because it's not present in all implementations. One thing I don't like about using `traceback` is that you then have to start generating fake exceptions to get at information.