# How do i access a class through input

Tags: python, class

I put together a small test code just to demonstrate the error I am getting when trying to enter a class with input. Nothing pretty or good its just to get the specific error across.

Code:

```
class people(object):
    def deposit():
        print("depositing")
    def withdraw():
        print("withdrawing")
John = people()
selection = input("Type John: ")
selection.deposit
```

Error:

```
[evaluate classes.py]
Type John: John
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Peter\Desktop\Desktop 2\Python\classes.py", line 9, in module
    selection.deposit
builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'deposit'
```

Comment: what do you mean by `enter a class with input`? This is a classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

If it's only for demonstration purposes you could lookup the `selection` value in the `locals()` dict:

```
In [4]: John = 1

In [5]: selection = "John"

In [6]: locals()[selection]
Out[6]: 1
```

So, your code would look like:

```
class people(object):
    def deposit(self):
        print("depositing")
    def withdraw(self):
        print("withdrawing")
John = people()
selection = input("Type John: ")
locals()[selection].deposit()
```

However, please do not use this approach in production code. There are better patterns for dispatching stuff to objects..

Comment: Did you test the code before posting? The functions should have `self` as the minimum argument and `locals()[selection].deposit` should be `locals()[selection].deposit()`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't want this kind of direct correspondence between user input and your internal variable names. You'd have some data structure to keep track of your `people` instances, perhaps a dict:

```
known_people = {'John': people(), 'Jake': people(), 'Jeffrey', people()}
```

and you'd process user input to determine what to do with your data:

```
selected_person = known_people[selection]
selected_person.deposit()
```

While you technically can access variables dynamically:

```
John = people()
selected_person = locals()[selection]
```

you really, really shouldn't. It doesn't scale well to more complex data, and it introduces potential for lots of nasty bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the people (like John) in a separate object (like a dictionary).

Consider that approach:

```
class Man(object):
    # I renamed the `people` class to `Man` since it's representing a single man (like John).
    # You also have to add a required `self` parameter for every function inside of the class!
    def deposit(self):
        print("depositing")

    def withdraw(self):
        print("withdrawing")

# We'll make `people` a dictionary instead.
people = {
    'John': Man()
}

selection = raw_input("Type John: ")

# You have to put parentheses there so the `deposit()` function would call
people[selection].deposit()
```

[`eval()` is pretty evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice), [so as `locals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550479/python-is-using-vars-locals-a-good-practice).

Answer (score -1):

`input("Type John: ")` returns a string, not an object of type `people` so you can't call the method `deposit` on it.

**Workaround-**

```
class people(object):
    def deposit(self):
        print("depositing")
    def withdraw(self):
        print("withdrawing")
selection = input("Type people(): ")
selection.deposit()
```

**Input-**

```
people()
```

**Output-**

```
depositing
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @tuxtimo I have successfully tested it before posting, unlike you! ;)

Comment: of course you did. lol. You will get a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'deposit'` error after entering "John" or whatever, but yes of course you've tested it ;)

Comment: @tuxtimo Did you read this- `input("Type people(): ")` And did you check what I am supplying as input- `people()`

Comment: @tuxtimo Do check it before replying. As i said, I have already tested it! :)

Comment: `>>> selection = input("Type people(): ")`
`Type people(): John`
`>>> selection.deposit()`
`depositing`

Comment: @tuxtimo That's on Python 3, do check the screenshot that I have added to my answer. I use Python 2.

Comment: @CrakC you are running python 2 does why. I run python 3

Comment: yeah it does, some non-believer just downvoted me :(

Comment: for python 3 use: eval(input("..."))

Comment: @tuxtimo That's right! I believe we are at peace now. ;)

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes Yes you were but other parts of the code were incorrect. Thanks for the upvote though. :)

Comment: @CrakC Yes, we are ;)

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes LOL! Looks like that. Well, you can as well repost the answer with the obvious corrections that I wrote as comments. :) It's your day today. ;)

Comment: @CrakC My first upvote is a wrong answer... Hmm maybe I should try it more often